# React native ad services integration for android platform

Tags: react-native

I am building a application using React Native and would like to integrate Ad services (Admob,inmobi etc..) in my application for Android.

I found one sample for iOS using Admob framework, https://github.com/melihmucuk/react-native-admob-sample

Can anyone point out if there is any such support for available for Android?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be useful for the original post anymore. But it might help other people who pop by this post in future. 
Their official tutorial was good for initial set-up. 
https://rnfirebase.io/
But it doesn’t really tell you how to display ads once the install is done. I found the following blog post very helpful in that space. 
https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/